# RegEx - Remove HTML hyperlinks based on the link text

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have some text that has HTML hyper-links in it.
I want to remove the hyperlinks, but only specific ones.

e.g. I start with this:

```
This is text <a href="link/to/somewhere">Link to Remove</a> and more text with another link <a href="/link/to/somewhere/else">Keep this link</a>
```

I want to have:

```
This is text and more text with another link <a href="/link/to/somewhere/else">Keep this link</a>
```

I have this RegEx expression,

```
<a\s[^>]*>.*?</a>
```

... but it matches ALL of the links.

What do I need to add to that expression to match only the links with the link-text 'Remove' (for example) in it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably get a lot of feedback not to use regular expressions on HTML... but if you do decide to use one, try this:

```
 <a\s[^>]*>.*?Remove.*?</a>
```

This is where "Remove" lies somewhere in the link text.

Comment: Thanks, that got it.   

And if I wanted to match on 'remove' with case insensitivity, what would I wrap that in? (e.g. match on 'Remove' or 'remove' or 'REMOVE' etc...)

Comment: @Rob: Pretty sure C# has something like `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` that you can pass in as another param.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=~/(.*)<a.*<\/a>([a-z ]+ <a.*<\/a>)/;
print "$1$2";
```

Answer (score 0):

(.*?)<a.*[Rr]emove.*?a>(.*)

reconstruct with: $1$2